# Zend Framework Application Runtime Benchmarking

Tags: performance, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Been trying to understand the overall performance of our application by comparing the benchmark we get from our dev environment and our prod environment.

Interestingly, in our dev environment, which is our local machine, we get application run time as fast as 98ms.

The same application runs on avg at 400ms in our production server, which is a VPS with CentOS  5.8 running.

I'm assuming that this increase must be because of network connection lag between web server and database server, since we didn't have this gap in the dev environment, everything is local.

We're using Doctrine 2.0 as an ORM for our application, we haven't really gotten into optimizing it by caching.

Is there a way to optimize this lag time? Or am I completely wrong about the case?

Comment: Is whatever you are using to measure performance counting network latency?  Zend Debugger or XDebug have features that can profile your application and give a good overview of performance and it only measures the code runtime and nothing else like network or dns.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to measure actual database and query time used is to setup a database profiler.

You can read this: [Profiling Doctrine 2 with Zend Framework](http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/profiling-doctrine-2-with-zend-framework/)

Just as a note, running a profiler should only be done for testing. You shouldn't run it all the time, especially if your production server is high volume. It will add some processing time, but it will give you more information about your queries and connection time.

Your assumption of it being latency between the boxes could be true and this will verify it for you.